# String indices must be integers (error) when accessing dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.6

```
def generate_spell_damage(self, i):
        mgl = self.magic[i]['dmg'] - 5
        mgh = self.magic[i]['dmg'] + 5
        return random.randrange(mgl, mgh)


magic = [{'name': 'Fire', 'cost': 20, 'dmg': 30},
     {'name': 'Blizzard', 'cost': 30, 'dmg': 60},
     {'name': 'Storm', 'cost': 10, 'dmg': 80}]

Person = Player(200, 100, 60, 40, 'magic')
print(Person.generate_spell_damage(1))
```

error : string indices must be integers. 
please help me get through this error. your help will be appreciated

Comment: what is in `self.magic[i]['dmg']` i think there is something with type `str` not `int`, can you show all class ?

Comment: @zim there's the number 60 (in theory)

Comment: please show us the traceback, not only the error message.

Comment: ``in theory`` don't work, can you `print(type(self.magic[i]['dmg']))` ?

Comment: Shot in the dark: you have an instance variable named `magic` whose value is a string, shadowing the dict you intended to access. We can't do any more than throw out guesses with just these edited fragments to go on, though.

Comment: I'm trying to edit it with the full code for you guys but stack isn't letting me do it. It is telling me to add more details. I don't get it. I'm new here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you populate the Player object with 'magic' shouldn't is be

```
Person = Player(200, 100, 60, 40, magic)
```

Otherwise it would be interpreted as string.

Comment: Thanks! The code is working. I can sleep now. :v